# How can i get my twilio details with curl?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I want to get my twilio all phone numbers and my other details. which url to hit? how can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you checked the [Twilio documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/)? All of the examples have the code for curl as well as the other helper libraries. Is there anything specific you are having trouble with?

Comment: yes. I check it but I want my client to be able to check his twilio number from a list to which he can send sms from.. can YOu please help @philnash

Comment: What do you need help with? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have no idea where to start.. can you please try on postman or something... I'm unable to find the twilio api url which I should hit..

Comment: You mentioned getting your phone numbers. Here's [the documentation for listing phone numbers from the API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/incoming-phone-numbers?code-sample=code-list-all-incomingphonenumber-of-your-account&code-language=curl&code-sdk-version=json). I've linked you to the `curl` example for listing your numbers. Does that get you started?

Comment: Thanks that helped me a lot. Do you know how can I make other to reply to my twilio? msg?

Comment: Not sure what you mean there. Twilio messages are SMS messages, so to reply to them you need to send an SMS